How to config express app to run on port XXXX in NX
Project Overview

admin and client are react apps generated by

npx nx generate @nx/react:application

for the api

npx nx @nx/node:application

In the context of react, updating the project.json did the thing
project.json
"targets": {
    "serve": {
      "options": {
        "port": 3000
      }
    }
  },

In the api 
main.ts
import express from 'express';
import logger from './utils/logger';
const host = process.env.API_HOST ?? 'localhost';
const port = process.env.API_PORT ? Number(process.env.API_PORT) : 5001;

const app = express();

app.use(logger);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ message: 'Hello API' });
});

app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`[ ready ] http://${host}:${port}`);
});

Is there any way to explicitly use the project.json properties for the express server without evnironment-variables?
